# React + Firestore . db.collection...set({date:date}) ==> nothing is happening

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am a noob in react. 
I am trying to upload the date selected from datetimepicker to firestore.

Ive put the statement db.collection in the onchange function. But nothing is happening.
No errors. No logs. Nothing. Same in the firebase console. 
While console Logs are working.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DateTimePicker from 'react-datetime-picker';
import { db } from "../firebase";



class Picker extends Component {
  state = {
    date: new Date(),
  }

  onChange = date => this.setState({ date },
    function(){
      const DateContext =this.state.date;
      db.collection("date_selected").doc('date_selected').set({date:DateContext});

    })

  render() {

    return (

      <div>
        <DateTimePicker
          onChange={this.onChange}
          value={this.state.date}
        />
         { console.log(this.state.date) }

         )}         
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Picker;
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: I am not at all versed in React but shouldn't you do       `db.collection("date_selected").doc('date_selected').set({date:DateContext});`?

Comment: thanks Renaud, i edited. But i'm still not getting anything. For the sake of the example i replaced the variable with a string 'test'.

Comment: You'd better not use string but something more meaningful in the set. Test with real date format to make sure it is working on Firebase end.

Comment: Aren't you missing a ";" after the constant before the database call?@GuillaumeLabs

Comment: Thanks CyberMessiah, this was missing, i edited. But i still get the same results : nothing.

Comment: Where are you checking if the state has been updated? Do you have the Redux Chrome extension for example?